# Eclipse Team Synchronizing view show commiter on incomming changes

Tags: eclipse, view, synchronization

Can the  *Team Synchronizing* view in *Eclipse* show on incoming changes which user has performed them? Currently the view looks like this (I blurred the file names):

[image]

Each time I would like to know who committed the changes, I need to open the *History* view. This is really inconvenient. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any settings on the preferences. I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using `Eclipse Mylyn` with `Change sets`. Incoming changes are now grouped by the task id from SCM and also mention the user that is responsible for the changes. With the new grouping the synchronization is even more convenient - I can decide by task if I want to pick up the changes. I'm still using `Subversive`.

I nice tutorial about `Mylyn Change sets` can be found at the [tasktop website](https://tasktop.com/blog/mylyn/mastering-eclipse-change-sets).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to open the History view repeatedly; just keep it open and as you select files in the Synchronize view, the History view will automatically update itself to show the history of the selected file. Just make sure your History view has the "Link with Editor and Selection" toolbar selected (it looks like two yellow arrows pointing in opposite directions).